# Is there an error with Late Answers Review?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

Well short and clear. watch this:

[image]

is this a bug?, maybe is an error of our network and will grant to reviewers to farm.

Comment: I was just wondering the same thing. It's also allowed me to review over 20 for the day so far.

Comment: i'm afraid to abuse this thing because it could eventually be a bug.

Comment: @bertieb , i really havent  idea :S

Comment: I am assuming it has something to do with this [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue?cb=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a result of [raising the reputation level of what should be slotted into the Late Answers review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue).

> [...] I'd like to try raising the reputation for getting enqueued to the Late Answer reviews to 50 and reconsider upping it to 100 at some point in the future.

Previously it was at 10 reputation.

Comment: so, should i start to review?

Comment: Yes, charge headlong into the fray and be ready with your helmet

Comment: ok, sir, ill take my claymore and start to slay Last Answers ASAP

Comment: O ye gods, *what have Jon Ericson's careless hands wrought*? Once more unto the breach, dear friends, once more...

Comment: The late answers queue is supposed to be new answers to old questions.  I looked at a few, and they were all very old answers to very old questions.  The few I looked at didn't look like they were selected due to an apparent problem.  So why are we reviewing random old answers?  I suspect a programming error.  Raising the rep level was expected to roughly double or triple the size of the queue.  The queue is now at least 2,000 times bigger and the answers selected don't match the nature of the queue.

Comment: Right on, @fixer1234. There's really not much sense in reviewing something older than a few months, and the material in the queue in general (after reviewing a couple of them) seems to be extremely good. Unless someone marks them reviewed programmatically it'll take quite a while for the queue to get emptied...

Comment: Looks like it's really time for people to wade through the mass (quoting comment from [meta.SE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue?cb=1): "@Sven: Reverting won't help, I'm afraid. The damage has been done. I have gone over to pitch in on Server Fault as an act of penitence. –  Jon Ericson♦ 11 hours ago "